# Batch editing of circle diameters using attribute table in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, attribute-table, editing, circle

I need to edit the diameter of a bunch of circles to reflect their correct diameters, and I wondered if there was a way of drawing from the attribute table to make all the circles equal their correct diameters rather than redrawing all the circles with the correct diameters by hand?

Comment: There is an ArcGIS Idea to [**modify circle size**](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bvZBAAY) that you may want to vote for and add a comment to that includes a link that comes here.

Answer (score 3):

After making a comment about GENERATE CIRCLE just now it dawned on me that you could use [**Buffer**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000019000000) to generate circles using the field value you have for Radius.  Then, after making sure that you have transferred the attributes from your original (wrong-sized) circles to the new ones from Buffer, you could [**Append**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000050000000) in the new and [**Select**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000005000000) out the old to update your feature class.

Comment: Without knowing the current radius I'd think you'd want to first convert the circles to centroids before buffering them by the desired radius. Or you could estimate the current radius by dividing the perimeter by 2*pi, calculate the difference between that and the desired radius and buffer by that amount.

Comment: @blah238 - yeah, I should have mentioned that [**Add XY Coordinates**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000032000000) might be a useful tool in the workflow to

Answer (score 1):

I imagine this would require some custom programming.

In ArcObjects you could use the [`ITransform2D.Scale`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000003w7000000) method to resize the features' geometry.

Comment: My recollection is that this would have been very easy to do in AML - simply GENERATE with CIRCLE option and then APPEND into spatial dataset - Create Fishnet is still very poor substitute for GENERATE :-)

Answer (score 1):

One approach I have not seen posted yet is using a buffer of your circles and using either a positve value for the buffer radius if you want the circle to be larger or a negative value for the buffer radius if you want the circle smaller.